# Block by a simple acl authentication for selenium test

Tags: java, tomcat, selenium

I'm trying to write selenium tests for a web site.

I used a Tomcat server with a MemoryRealm authentication cf 
 `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" pathname="/DEV/tomcat1/conf/tomcat-users.xml"/>`

I didn't see how to set authentication in my tests. I tried to put in "selenium.open"

```
selenium.open("http://user:pass@myserver:8080/index.jsp");
```

Selenium launched the server, opened the web site, but stays on auth without filling the user/password form.

Is it just not possible and do I have to change tomcat auth, or did I just miss something?

Comment: Do you have a basic authentication dialog window or a form login screen ? The docs state passing in user:password in URL does not work in IE

Comment: it's a basic authentication dialog windows, and yes i saw it doesn't work with IE, i tested with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

i try the same and for mi it work in some case.
for example:

this work only for apache in linux and in some IIS
$this->setBrowserUrl("http://USER:PASSWORD@IP:PORT");

Comment: I thought, maybe it works with a IIS/Apache authentication, but not a tomcat authentication.